# If $p(n)$ be the $n$-th prime number, is $\lim_{n\to \infty} {p(n)}^\frac{1}{n}$ exist and how we can find it if exist?

Tags: limits, cauchy-sequences

In my research, I need a counterexample of sequences, and $p(n)$, the $n$- prime number sequence is an important sequence to me. Generally for an arbitrary sequence of the real and positive numbers, such as $a(n)$,
any classification of the $\lim_{n\to \infty} {a(n)}^\frac{1}{n}$ will be useful to me.
However, according to my calculation, this limit must be greater than $1.76151$.

Comment: Can you show the work that gave you that limit? I’m extremely curious.

Comment: What calculations? I am curious. With $n=100$ I got $\sqrt[100]{541}\approx 1.06$

Comment: My estimate is related to polynomial root boundaries by the coefficients. I need time to recheck that.

Comment: I was wrong in my estimate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Prime Number Theorem implies $p(n) \sim n \log n$, so $p(n)^{1/n} \to 1$.

Answer (score 2):

The $n$th prime is roughly $n\log n$ therefore
$$\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}(n \log n)^{1/n}=1$$